# Setup my new Mac

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, password, user-account, settings

I just bought a MacBook Pro and it's a beauty. I haven't opened it yet. I expect it to ask my about the language and for an account. That's cool, however I was wondering if there is something I could do, so that i**t won't ask me for a password** every fOcking time I the laptop goes to sleep automatically (because e.g. I was on the phone).

Any ideas?

Comment: There are settings for that inside System Preferences.

Comment: So I should not do something the 1st time I open my Mac? Sorry, but it's my first time manipulating a brand new one @IronCraftMan! Also are you sure, I asked my colleague if I can do it via settings later and he said no.. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go into system preferences (click on the apple icon in the top left corner of your screen) and go into "Security & Privacy", there is an option to disable the password after sleep.

[image: Security and Privacy]